# Erlang `now-next` list iteration

Tags: erlang

I am trying to write something similar to the following:

haskell:

```
Prelude> let xs = [1..10]
Prelude> zip xs (tail xs)
[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(6,7),(7,8),(8,9),(9,10)]
```

erlang:

```
1> XS = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
2> lists:zip(XS, tl(XS)).
** exception error: no function clause matching lists:zip("\n",[]) (lists.erl, line 321)
     in function  lists:zip/2 (lists.erl, line 321)
     in call from lists:zip/2 (lists.erl, line 321)


now_nxt([X|Tail],XS) -> 
    [Y|_] = Tail,
    now_nxt(Tail, [{X,Y}|XS]);
now_nxt(_,XS) -> XS.

156>coeffs:now_nxt(XS, []).
** exception error: no match of right hand side value []
```

update:

thank you for the example. I ended up writing the following:

```
now_nxt_nth(Index, XS) ->
    nnn(Index, XS, []).


nnn(Index, XS, YS) ->
    case Index > length(XS) of
    true  ->
        lists:reverse(YS);
    false ->
        {Y,_} = lists:split(Index, XS),
        nnn(Index, tl(XS), [Y|YS])
    end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One (simple and efficient) solution from many possible:

```
now_nxt([H|T]) ->
  now_nxt(H, T).

now_nxt(_, []) -> [];
now_nxt(A, [B|T]) -> [{A, B} | now_nxt(B, T)].
```

Answer (score 1):

The lists have to be of equal size when using `lists:zip` , tl(XS) will obviously be one shorter than XS.

```
 lists:zip(XS--[lists:last(XS)], tl(XS)).
```

I think that achieves what you're trying to do by removing the last element from the first input list.

Comment: so then to be able to use this as a general function on must first test `xs % 2`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `xs % 2` , if you mean length of list >= 2 then yes you must or let it fail and catch the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is:

```
lists:zip(lists:sublist(XS,length(XS)-1), tl(XS)).
```

It should be noted that

```
L--[lists:last(L)]
```

may not remove the last element. For instance,

```
L = [1,2,3,4,1].
L -- [lists:last(L)] =/= [1,2,3,4]. % => true
[2,3,4,1] = L -- [lists:last(L)].
```